# MySQL - Change date string to date type in place?

Tags: sql, mysql, date

(Hi all. I'm new-ish to SQL and MySQL in particular. I know some PHP.)

I have a table which contains a "date_string" column. For legacy reasons, this is a text field, containing the date in d/m/YY format.  e.g. "22/11/09" for 22nd November 2009.

Question: how could I convert all fields in this column to a standard MySQL date format (YYYY-mm-dd), in-place?

Or, failing being able to change it in place, given that the column type is text, how could I take each existing text-based date, and create a standard date in another column (of type 'date') within the table?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(textdate, '%d/%m/%y') FROM MyTable...
```

Or create another column with `DATE` data type and copy the values:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN realdate DATE;
UPDATE MyTable SET realdate = STR_TO_DATE(textdate, '%d/%m/%y');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  When I try either option, I get "NULL" as the results for all fields.

Specifically, if I do this:

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('%d/%m/%y', date_string) FROM myTable

Then I get a list of NULL values, one for each record.  "date_string" is of varchar type, 32 chars max.  Dates are currently stored as "19/3/05", "1/8/07", etc.

Comment: Sorry, I got the arguments reversed.  I'll edit the above examples to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    UPDATE your_table
    SET your_col = '20'
              + substring(your_col, 
                          LOCATE('/', your_col, LOCATE('/', your_col) + 1) + 1
                         )
              + '-'
              + substring(your_col, 
                          LOCATE('/', your_col) + 1, 
                          LOCATE('/', your_col, LOCATE('/', your_col) + 1)
                         )
              + '-'
              + substring(your_col, 1, LOCATE('/', your_col) - 1)


/*
    LOCATE('/', your_col) -> search for 1st occurence of '/' in your_col
    LOCATE('/', your_col, LOCATE('/', your_col) + 1) -> search for 2nd occurence of '/' in your_col
    LOCATE('/', your_col, LOCATE('/', your_col) + 1) + 1 -> from where to retriev the last part
*/
```

(I suppose year >= 2000)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, the year in this case is always >= 2000. However, the strings themselves are of variable length, as "1/1/01" has been recorded along with dates like "31/12/09".  Would both dates survive your algorithm? Cheers.

Comment: 1st version will not apply to '1/1/01'. Amended. Now it will work for both.

Answer (score 0):

if you have trouble doing this from within MySQL, you could try with php by converting the dates using strtotime()

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my next step. But, Bill's edited example now works, so that's a PHP job saved.  Cheers.