# Date clashes between form and database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If the user provides a date in the format via aform **($date_booked)**:

```
2012-1-6
```

to be compared against a date **(date_booked)**:

```
2012-01-06
```

What would be the correct SQL method to check it be (using phpMyAdmin):

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE date_booked LIKE $date_booked
```

Or would MySQL not return anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SQL database system? Which programming language? The right answer is to convert the string into a date/datetime in the programming language, then pass that as a date/datetime parameter to the database, but examples can't be provided without knowing these details. (And of course, to hope that the DB is storing this value as a datetime; But it's probably better, if not, from a correctness perspective to force a conversion (to datetime) during querying, and, if performance is an issue, to use this as a reason for a schema change)

Comment: I've added MySQl and php as tags. I *believe* the phpMyAdmin is a general querying tool, and not a technology used by a "form", so I don't believe that that's part of the actual question. (I also further assume that, if you're using phpMyAdmin, this also implies that your general language is PHP. At this point I have no idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using TSQL and user entered a correct date

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE date_booked = CONVERT(date, @UserEnteredDate)
```

**As you have updated your question to MySQL**

Here is a good example on how to compare date [MySQL - Change date string to date type in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408285/mysql-change-date-string-to-date-type-in-place)

Comment: Almost right with the code formatting - you need to indent by *four* spaces (or hit the `{}` button).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Human error once in a while. Thanks for pointing that up.. +1

Comment: And mostly for nowt. I'm sure the original question didn't have technology details (hence my first comment to it), but it turns out it's MySQL. So `CONVERT` won't work (I'd expect `CAST` should)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Believe me or not, I just tried to format (as usual 4 spaces) my `SELECT ..` query but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming PHP from the `$variable` notation

Using the `date_parse()` function in PHP it is easy to compare the two dates even though they appear syntactically different :

```
date_parse('2012-1-6');

array (
  'year' => 2012,
  'month' => 1,
  'day' => 6,
  'hour' => false,
  'minute' => false,
  'second' => false,
  ...
)
```

```
date_parse('2012-01-06');

array (
  'year' => 2012,
  'month' => 1,
  'day' => 6,
  'hour' => false,
  'minute' => false,
  'second' => false,
  ...
)
```

On a side note you should consider storing your date/time information in an Unix timestamp (seconds since 01/01/1970) in your database - much easier to perform calculations on.  PHP has [a weath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) of date/time functions.

If you do end up storing your dates and times as Unix timestamp then you could use PHP's [`strtotime()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) :

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

Comment: Most databases (MySQL included) have datetime types built in. It is *far* better to use these types, rather than trying to "imply" meaning to other types, such as string, int or decimal.

Comment: What you say is correct @Damien.  My experience/habits remind me that epoch timestamps are universal - if an engine supports date/time then it will recognize epoch (correct me if I'm wrong).  I think its still a good portable and easy to use choice.

Comment: epoch timestamps are universal - so long as everyone interpreting the data is aware of the epoch? That moves away from the intent of relational databases - that the data should be usable without outside references