# Invalid result when 2 dates (String) are compared

Tags: mysql, sql, date, varchar, str-to-date

I have a table called `test` in my MySQL database. Below is the how it is created.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `update_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `value` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Below is its data.

[image]

I run the below query as described in the selected answer of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927247/how-can-i-query-between-two-dates-with-the-date-field-is-a-string)

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `test`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`update_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-10-2014' AND '31-10-2014'
```

This should return 1800, but instead it returned `NULL`. Why is this and how can I get the correct answer?

**Very Important:** I have to use `String` for `Date` because I must save date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format and mysql `Date` do not accept it.

Comment: Mysql date does NOT store the date in any specific format. In fact the date is usually stored as an offset from a base date (a decimal value). Don't use strings to store dates, use date. How your date is displayed or compared is up to you but converting from string to date all the time WILL impact performance

Comment: Looking at the docs it suggests that `DATE` is stored as 3 bytes. The docs are misleading to newbies though as they say the data is retrieved and displayed in YYYY-MM-DD. This doesn't mean it's stored in that format. Don't use strings, convert your dates in your queries. Think about it - it takes one function call to convert a date parameter, but it takes one function call PER ROW to convert data in your tables to go from string to date. Add to that the fact that indexes won't be utilised because of the scalar applied to the column and you are asking for poor performance

Comment: Just to throw a bit more ammo at justifications for not spring dates as strings http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: @Charleh:You mean the `Date` object can be saved in `dd-mm-yyyy` ? I went through lot of questions, posts and examples, all say it is not.

Comment: It's not saved in any format - it's saved as a series of bits (3 bytes which is 24 bits, e.g. `000010100011100101011010`) which likely represent an offset from a point in the past. You retrieve dates in MySQL in `YYYY-MM-DD` format but how you display them is up to your application layer, not the database layer. If you are using the database layer to format a date you are usually doing it wrong. If you are storing dates as strings you will impact performance because converting a date string is costly vs comparing the 24 bits a date is stored as. Format the date in your app not your SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `test`
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`update_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') 
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31-10-2014', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

or you could also do this:

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `test`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`update_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') 
BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'  -- in Y-m-d
```

Both the queries should return ***1800***.

Note that [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) returns the [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) value ,which is in `Y-m-d` format.